# SharePoint 2019 - Quick Links Opening in New Tab

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, quick-links

Currently we are using SharePoint 2019 On-Prem and when using the Quick Links web part if the link is to a page on the site or to a Document Library it is opening in a new tab rather than in the same window.

Documents are also being downloaded from Document Libraries/Highlighted Content rather than using the browser to view them (files are PDF)

Any thoughts on why this would happen or what configuration may be missed?

Answer (score 0):

1.In the Quick links web part, when you click the link refers to a page on the site or to a document library, it opens in a new tab rather than in the same window. It's by default.

2.Add PDF to the web application’s trusted MIME Type List
open the SharePoint Management Shell as administrator, and then run PowerShell commands:

```
 $webApplication = Get-SPWebApplication("http://sp/")  ## web application URL
 $webApplication.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add("application/pdf")
 $webApplication.Update()
```

Comment: For point 1, is there any way to change this logic to be same tab based?

Comment: Unfortunately setting the application has had no effect and our documents still download. Is there anything else the may effect this functionality?